# Поменять местами компоненты в файле

Tags: c, файлы, функции

Поменять местами положительные компоненты.

Помогите доработать код. Пожалуйста, очень нужно.

---

```
    puts("Содержимое файла:");
    print_file(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    if (x < 0) {
        first = x;
        fread(&first, sizeof(double), 1, f);
    }
    fseek(f, -sizeof(double), SEEK_END);
    if (x > 0) {
        last = x;
        fread(&last, sizeof(double), 1, f);
    }

    temp = first;
    first = last;
    last = temp;

    puts("Файл:");
    print_file(f);
    fclose(f);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Почему бы в цикле чтения не запомнить позиции первого и последнего отрицательных чисел и не посчитать их?

Comment: Помогите это реализовать,пожалуйста

Comment: **Поменять местами положительные компоненты.** постановка задачи совершенно бредовая. Вот вам файл, который содержит всего три(!) числа: 1.0, 2.0, и 3.0. И что Вы с чем собрались менять местами? Единицу с двойкой, или единицу с тройкой? А может - двойку с тройкой?  А когда Вы единицу с двойкой поменяете, после этого единицу (на новом месте) с тройкой менять надо?  И когда этот процесс остановиться? Разберитесь с постановкой задачи сначала, а уж потом про *fseek()* разговаривать.

Answer (score 1):

Если считать, что в `print_file` чтение сделано верно, то позиции можно запомнить примерно так:

```
int negcnt = 0;
int pos = 0;
int firstpos, lastpos;
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
while (fread(&x, sizeof(double), 1, f)) {
   if (x<0) {
      if (!negcnt)
         firstpos = pos;
      lastpos = pos;
      negcnt++;
   }
   pos += sizeof(double);
}
```

Встали fseek в lastpos, прочитали значение, запомнили last.
Встали fseek в firstpos, прочитали значение, запомнили first.
Отмотали назад fseek от SEEK_CUR, записали last.
Встали fseek в lastpos, записали first.
Встали fseek в SEEK_END, дописали количество.

Comment: а как позиции можно поменять местами?

Comment: `fseek(..)` вам в помощь

Comment: Как-то так?   fseek(f, firstpos, SEEK_SET);   fread(&x1, sizeof(double), 1, f);   fseek(f, lastpos, SEEK_SET);   fread(&x2, sizeof(double), 1, f);   fseek(f, firstpos, SEEK_SET);   fwrite(&x2, sizeof(double), 1, f);   fseek(f, lastpos, SEEK_SET);   fwrite(&x1, sizeof(double), 1, f);

Comment: Да, где-то так. pos я перевел в байты, чтобы непосредственно использовать в fseek